# SQLite unique constraint on multiple column without order

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique-constraint

I need help on a problem in my table definitions : I have a table which will be defined, for example, like this :

- `id`, primary key
- `friend0_id`, foreign key on table `users`
- `friend1_id`, foreign key on table `users`

The problem is I do not want to have multiple times the couple `(friend0_id, friend1_id)`, whatever the order the are in the table.

I tried to define an `UNIQUE` constraint on the couple `(friend0_id, friend1_id)`, but the columns order defined in the constraint (here `friend0_id`, THEN `friend1_id`) matters. So :

```
| id | friend0_id | friend1_id |
|----|------------|------------|
| 1  |      3     |      4     | -> OK
| 2  |      4     |      3     | -> OK, as the columns order in index matters
| 3  |      3     |      4     | -> Not OK, constraint prevent this
```

I would like the id 2 and 3 in the example to be disallowed, but I can't figure how. Do you have some tips for me ?

Thank you,
naccyde

Comment: The usual solution would be to create a constraint on `(greatest(friend0_id, friend1_id), least(friend0_id, friend1_id))` but I don't know how to do that with SQLite. SQLite has `max` and `min` functions to replace `greatest` and `least` but I don't think it lets you index on expressions.

Comment: @muistooshort Expression indexes are supported since version 3.9.0.

Answer (score 3):

As [@mu too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346285/sqlite-unique-constraint-on-multiple-column-without-order#comment75696245_44346285) mentioned, the way is to use `(greatest(friend0_id, friend1_id), least(friend0_id, friend1_id))`, so, now I have a working 2 columns order free unique constraint. I did it in SQLite this way (which could not be the better) :

- Create a trigger which set `min(friend0_id, friend1_id)` to `friend0` and `max(friend0_id, friend1_id)` to `friend1` :

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER friend_fixed_id_order_trigger
  AFTER INSERT ON friends 
  BEGIN UPDATE friends 
    SET 
      friend0_id = min(NEW.friend0_id, NEW.friend1_id), 
      friend1_id = max(NEW.friend0_id, NEW.friend1_id) 
    WHERE friends.id = NEW.id; 
  END
  ```
- Then, set a unique constraint on the couple `(friend0_id, friend1_id)` :

  ```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `friends_unique_relation_index` 
  ON `contacts` (`friend0_id` ,`friend1_id`)
  ```

And it works !

**EDIT** : If someone need this tip, do not forget to create an update trigger too, otherwise an update request could break the mechanism.